# A $\subset$ B, A and B closed then B-A is open

Tags: general-topology, compactness

A  $\subset$ B, A and B closed then B-A is open

How can I prove this statement? Is that correct? I need it because is used to prove that a closed subset of a compact space is compact.

Imagine B=[0,4] and A=[1,2] contained in A, then B-A is neither open or closed, what am I doing wrong??

PS: maybe I need B compact in the statement, but the example works in every case.

Comment: "A ⊂ B, A and B closed then B-A is open".  Where did you hear this?  This is not true.

Comment: I believe Hinning Makholm is correct.  The claim should be:  Let be $A \subset B$, $A$ and $B$ closed sets in a compact space $X$.  Then $B-A$ is open *in the space $B$*.  It is obviously not open in the space $X$.

Comment: So $B-A = [0,1) \cup (2,4]$ which is very much open in $[0,4]$.

Comment: Thank you all, now it is clear. Indeed it seemed very strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing is that for "closed subset of a compact space is compact", $A$ is not only compact and closed: $A$ *is the entire space* and therefore *open*. Thus $A\setminus B = A\cap \overline B$ is open too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are considering $B$ as your ambient space, then $B-A$ would definitely be open but if your ambient space is something else then $B-A$ may or may not be open.

Answer (score 0):

Remember this:
If A is open and B is closed,then,

$1.$A-B is $\color{red}{open}$

$2.$B-A is $\color{red}{closed}$